# Is it possible to select the number of threads to run from inside a program? c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to do a program where you can select the number of threads to be executed, and I'm having problems to get it working. I've tried to first create the threads and then join all them depending on the selected number, but the programs doesn't detect the threads when I try to join them.

```
//####################### CREATE THREADS ###################
if (numProcs >= 1)
{
    thread t1(threadTask,repart[0],llargMax,contrassenya);

}
if (numProcs >= 2)
{
    thread t2(threadTask,repart[1],llargMax,contrassenya);

}
if (numProcs >= 3)
{
    thread t3(threadTask,repart[2],llargMax,contrassenya);
}
if (numProcs >= 4)
{
    thread t4(threadTask,repart[4],llargMax,contrassenya);

}

//################## JOIN THREADS ################################
if (numProcs >= 1)
{
    t1.join();
}
if (numProcs >= 2)
{
    t2.join();
}
if (numProcs >= 3)
{
    t3.join();
}
if (numProcs >= 4)
{
    t4.join();
}
```

I've also tried to join every thread just after creating it, but this stops my program and just one thread is joined at a time.

```
if (numProcs >= 1)
{
    thread t1(threadTask,repart[0],llargMax,contrassenya);
    t1.join();
}
if (numProcs >= 2)
{
    thread t2(threadTask,repart[1],llargMax,contrassenya);
    t2.join();
}
if (numProcs >= 3)
{
    thread t3(threadTask,repart[2],llargMax,contrassenya);
    t3.join();
}
if (numProcs >= 4)
{
    thread t4(threadTask,repart[4],llargMax,contrassenya);
    t4.join();
}
```

And finally I tried to detach the threads, this works if at the end of my main program I wait for a decent amount of time, so every thread can finish before quiting the program, but I don't know how to detect when all detached threads have ended, so my program can work with larger threads.

```
if (numProcs >= 1)
{
    thread t1(threadTask,repart[0],llargMax,contrassenya);
    t1.detach()
}
if (numProcs >= 2)
{
    thread t2(threadTask,repart[1],llargMax,contrassenya);
    t2.detach();
}
if (numProcs >= 3)
{
    thread t3(threadTask,repart[2],llargMax,contrassenya);
    t3.detach();
}
if (numProcs >= 4)
{
    thread t4(threadTask,repart[4],llargMax,contrassenya);
    t4.detach();
}
sleep(100)
```

I've tried all those methods, but now I'm stuck and I don't know what I can try. Any ideas on how to do this will help me a lot.

Comment: Use a *container*. This question is no different from "is it possible to select the number of Employees to read at runtime". Or Students. Or Animals.

Comment: Also use a *loop*. You need to loop from 0 to `numProc-1` and do everything you want.

Comment: In the first code sample you declare the threads in local scope. How does it even compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because `{...}` block defines a separate scope so `t1, ...` variables do not exist outside of them.

Instead of that use some container, e.g.

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;

for (int i = 0; i < numProcs; i++) {
    auto t = std::thread(threadTask, repart[i], llargMax, contrassenya);
    threads.push_back(std::move(t));
}

// later

for (auto& t : threads) {
    t.join();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a container, like a *vector*. It should be something like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  size_t num_threads = 123;

  std::vector<std::thread> vect_threads(num_threads);
  for (auto& th : vect_threads) {
    th = std::thread ( /*...*/ );
  }

  // main branch ... stuff...      

  for (auto& th : vect_threads) {
    if (th.joinable()) {
      th.join();
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried to first create the threads and then join all them depending on the selected number, but the programs doesn't detect the threads when I try to join them.

You created all the `std::thread` objects as local variables. After the `if` blocks, they're *gone*.

**Store them in a container instead.**

> I've also tried to join every thread just after creating it, but this stops my program and just one thread is joined at a time.

What's the point in that? You're just running the thread entrypoints in sequence.

> I don't know how to detect when all detached threads have ended

You can't. They're detached.